# "docker logs" does not show any logs

Tags: docker, nginx, logging

I am setting up a NGINX node as container using docker compose file.

my compose file as below:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  reverse_proxy_nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.10-alpine
    container_name: reverse_proxy_nginx

    networks:
      external_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.10
    ports:
      - "80:80"

    volumes:    
      - ./static/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

    command: sh -c "rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/* &&
      nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
       
    tty: true


networks:
  external_net:
    external:
      name: localsw
```

after docker-compose up command:

```
[root@Site Reverse_Proxy]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                      PORTS                 NAMES
e1498798339d   nginx:1.19.10-alpine          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 seconds ago   **Exited (0) 5 seconds ago**                          reverse_proxy_nginx
```

"docker logs" command and -json.log all output nothing !!

```
[root@Site Reverse_Proxy]# docker logs reverse_proxy_nginx 
[root@Site Reverse_Proxy]# cat /var/lib/docker/containers/e1498798339d022ec5d744e1c557ca3e9f0779be114ffb0349acc9be1a70e5c7/e1498798339d022ec5d744e1c557ca3e9f0779be114ffb0349acc9be1a70e5c7-json.log 
[root@Site Reverse_Proxy]#
```

In my previous attempts, I did see "docker logs" output logs showing executing docker-entrypoint.sh and other shell scripts (10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh, 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh etc), also looking for default.conf file to initialize NGINX server. but now, it outputs nothing !!

I searched quite a long time on this issue, and did not find any solid & holistic solution yet. anyone knows where I should report this bug please ?

Comment: Please try `docker-compose logs` instead of `docker logs`

Comment: already tried many times, before I posted question here. no luck.  the problem is that JSON file (containerID-json.log) where the logs are permanently stored is empty.  That makes me suspect that default logging driver (json-file) is not working properly, it is very likely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

put below directive in config file solves the problem.

```
daemon off;
```